# LotusScript scheduled agent Refresh not processing computed fields with @DBLookup

Tags: lotusscript

I have a LotusScript scheduled agent that refreshes a view after adding many new records from a data sync process. The refresh works just fine except for any computed fields that use a @DBLookup. I also tried using ComputeWithForm before saving each new document. From what I have gathered, ComputeWithForm doesn't play well with @DBLookup, which is my only real sticking point. If there is a standard work around for that, please point me in the right direction. I have double checked that the Lookup server is the same as the agent server and that the server has Manager level access and all permissions to the documents and views. Thanks for all of your help.

requested code:

**Scheduled LotusScript agent**

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase

Set view = db.GetView("viewName")

Do
    Dim doc As New NotesDocument(db)

    --- other code that adds a new document---

    Call doc.ComputeWithForm(False, False)
    Call doc.Save(True, False)
Loop

Call view.Refresh()
```

**Computed Field formula code in document**

```
@DbLookup("Notes" : "NoCache"; "serverName" : "dbName.nsf"; "(columnName)"; fieldName; 2);
```

As stated above, the @DBLookup runs fine when run from the UI side of things, the scheduled agent runs fine, and the ComputeWithForm runs fine and updates all of the computed fields in the form, except for those with @DBLookup. My assumption that "ComputeWithForm doesn't play well with @DBLookup" comes from several other posts on this subject on Stack Overflow and other sources provided to me by our friend Google search.

[Refer to the IBM document "ComputeWithForm Does Not Compute Default Values Containing @Db Commands" (#146472) for more information.](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/LO55409)

Just to make sure it was attempting to refresh the computed field, I changed the computed field formula code to the following and I get the result "no name" when refreshed from the scheduled agent and the actual name when refreshed from the UI.

**Computed Field formula code in document**

```
empname := @DbLookup("Notes" : "NoCache"; "serverName" : "dbName.nsf"; "(columnName)"; fieldName; 2);
@If(@IsError(empname); "no name"; empname)
```

Comment: Computed fields are strictly UI items, so for them to update you have to open them from the UI.  With LotusScript all you can do is update the fields the computed fields use.

Comment: Please add CODE... Where do you put this code? How do you execute it? How do you "refresh" the view? How do you THINK that you recalculate the documents? Who told you that ComputeWithForm does not work well with @DBLookup? Your question is unanswerable as is and includes simply wrong premises...

Comment: added code above

Comment: Does it work if you **add** `Call doc.Save(True, False)` in front of `Call doc.ComputeWithForm(False, False)`?

Comment: yeah, I tried many different iterations of every combination possible and no help. I even tried recalling the view after adding all of the new documents and did a ComputeWithForm and Save on each, still no help. I have punted and will fake out the DBLookup  in the agent, using GetDocumentbyKey, and force feed it to the Form field manually instead of having a Default Value on the field on the Form.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a security issue. When you run from the UI, the user has access to the database, view, and documents referenced by the @DbLookup function. When you run it as an agent on the server, it is running under the server's ID, not a user's ID, and it does not have access. Even if the server name is in the ACL of both databases, it does not have access.

The old (as in 20+ years ago) solution to this was to put the replica id of the database containing the computed fields into the ACL of the database that is the target of the lookup. It's been a long time since I had to do this. I don't remember whether the replica id had to be exressed in the format where there are two 16-character parts separated by a colon, or as a single 32-character string. Using the replica ID was necessary because this was before agents were signed. The identity of the user who wrote the agent could not be established, and using the server's identity while running the agent would provide a backdoor for anyone with designer access for one database to read any other database on any server in the domain.

The new solution is to make sure that the signer of the agent has access to the target database by putting the signer's name (or a group) into the ACL of the target database, *and also* to fill in the Trusted Servers field in the Server Document. The name of the server where the database with the agent and computed fields resides must be in the Trusted Servers field in the Server Document of the server where the database that the @DbLookup is trying to access. This tells that server "It is okay to trust an agent signature as valid proof f access if it is presented in a session that was opened by this other server".

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried it a couple of different ways based on your advice, as the server, as the Administrator, as a user with all admin rights. None of them would trigger the recalculation of the computed fields' default values when they used @DBLookup. All of the other computed fields worked just fine, though. I am having better results force-feeding those fields from the agent using GetDocumentByKey. Thanks again.

Comment: Are these Computed-For-Display fields? There was an old, old issue with them that if you've stored a back-end item with the same name as a CFD field, the formula will never reevaluate. That's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: Oh, wait. That doesn't match the description. You say you get "No name". That means that the formula is executing. I still think it has to be an access issue, but your workaround is probably the best idea.

Comment: yeah, the lotusscript way of setting the form field using a GetDocumentbyKey statement works. Whatever gets you there. Thanks.